The Value of useReducer is not updating when console.logging it in a handleSubmit function
I'm using useReducer for my Login/Register form.
When I'm using logging the reducer value, it just returns the default value, whereas it works perfectly find when logging it on useEffect hook.
Here's a short part of my code:
//reducer

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_EMAIL":
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case "SET_NAME":
      return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// load reducer
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { email: "" });

//elements:

  const registerElements: Elements[] = [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "name",
      placeholder: "name",
      onChange: (e) => dispatch({ type: "SET_NAME", payload: e.target.value }),
      value: state.name || "",
    },
    {
      type: "email",
      name: "email",
      placeholder: "email",
      onChange: (e) => dispatch({ type: "SET_EMAIL", payload: e.target.value }),
      value: state.email || "",
    },
  ];



//functions
  function onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!recaptchaLoaded) return;
    window.grecaptcha.execute();
  }
  //Works perfectly fine, valid function is called 
  function scriptLoadReCAPTCHA() {
    setRecaptchaLoaded(true);
    window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
      window.grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
        sitekey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY,
        callback: action === "signin" ? signin : signup,
        size: "invisible",
      });
    });
  }

// Signup. I'm currently testing with signup only.
  function signup(token: string) {
    console.log(state);//output: {email: ''}
    fetch("/api/login/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        recaptcha: token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(state),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(console.log);
  }

//input
      <form className="my-8 flex flex-col gap-4" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
{(action === "signin" ? loginElements : registerElements).map(
          (loginElement) => (
            <input
              required
              key={loginElement.name}
              type={loginElement.type}
              name={loginElement.name}
              placeholder={loginElement.placeholder}
              onChange={loginElement.onChange}
              value={loginElement.value}
              className="w-full border-b-2 border-white bg-transparent px-0 py-1 capitalize text-white transition placeholder:text-gray-200 focus-visible:border-b-yellow focus-visible:outline-none"
            />
          ),
        )}
 ...
</form>

When I console.log it on submit, it remains the default value.
However, when I use useEffect like this:
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

It is logging the value as in the input
What can I do to fix this issue?

When I console.log it on submit, it remains the default value. where? I don't see any code reflecting this. Can you add your minimal reproducible code here

Hey @DecPK, I've added more info

Still not visible

@DecPK Default value is the second argument of useReducer i.e. { email: "" }
When I console.log it in signup function, it just logs that and not the actual state.
I'm not sure what you mean

I edited my function to this to fix the issue:
 function onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!recaptchaReady) return;
    console.log("executed");
    if(!recaptchaRendered){
    window.grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
      sitekey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY,
      callback: action === "signin" ? signin : signup,
      size: "invisible",
    });
    setRecaptchaRendered(true);
  } else {
    window.grecaptcha.reset()
  }
    window.grecaptcha.execute()
  }

